# Doubt in IMO 1982 problem 1

Tags: proof-explanation, contest-math, solution-verification, functional-equations, fake-proofs

**Question** -

The function $f(n)$ is defined for all positive integers $n$ and takes on non-negative integer values. Also, for all $m, n$
$$
\begin{array}{c}
f(m+n)-f(m)-f(n)=0 \text { or } 1 \\
f(2)=0, f(3)>0, \text { and } f(9999)=3333
\end{array}
$$
Find $f(1982)$
$$
(\mathrm{IMO}-1982)
$$

**My doubt** -

by putting $m=n=1$ we easily get $f(1)=0$..

now putting $n=1$ in given FE we get $f(m+1)=f(m)+0$ or $1$

now it can't be $0$ because then $f(3)=0$ contradicting the given fact that $f(3)>0$...
so hence $f(m+1)=f(m)+1$......(1)

now putting $n=2$ in given FE we get $f(m+2)=f(m)+0$ or $1$ 
(since $f(2)=0$ given )

but it can't be $0$ because then $f(3)=0$ contradicting the given fact that $f(3)>0$ again hence $f(m+2)=f(m)+1$ ......(2)

now combining $(1)$ and $(2)$ we get $f(m+1)=f(m+2)$ ***which is again contradicting, by putting $m=1$ that $f(3)=0$*** !!!!

how this can be true ...because i have taken all cases into considerations but then also getting contradiction ...where is the flaw ???

thankyou

Comment: I have it that $f(3)=1$, from putting $m=2$ and $n=1$ on the top line.   Since it's defined that $f(3)>0$.

Comment: yes,i know but then why it coming $f(3)=0$ that's what i am asking ,why there is a contradiction ???

Comment: User88463 not sure about the way you combined (1) and (2).  If you evaluated with $m=9997,n=2$ or likewise for 1 or 3 it may help with using that last bit of information?

Comment: User88463 not sure about the way you combined (1) and (2). The equalling 0 or 1 part may not have been handled correctly.  It's hard to say if the relation you started with remains the same relation, especially if you're removing a variable by setting $n=1$ If you evaluated with $m=9997,n=2$ or likewise for 1 or 3 it may help with using that last bit of information?

Comment: You can make the claim that $\boxed{f(4)=0 \text{or}1} \land \boxed{f(4)-1=0 \text{or}1}$ from 2+2=3+1

Comment: A given integer can be figured from smaller integers by considering all the different ways you can add to the given integer from two smaller integers

Comment: Tip: you can replace the entire first sentence with much shorter: Let $f:\Bbb N\to\Bbb N\cup\{0\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the functional equation, the term "$0$ or $1$" means that for each pair of integers $m, n$, the quantity $f(m + n) - f(m) - f(n)$ belongs to the set $\{0, 1\}$.

In particular, the value of $f(m + n) - f(m) - f(n)$ depends on $m, n$. It can be $0$ for some values of $m, n$, while being $1$ for others.

In your argument, when you come to $f(m + 1) = f(m) + 0$ or $1$, you seem to assume that this "$0$ or $1$" does not depend on $m$, which is an incorrect assumption.

Comment: thankyou very much...